# Cause of "The specified path is invalid" error when using ScheduledToastNotification

Tags: c#, toast, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm getting "The specified path is invalid" error when trying to show a ScheduledToastNotification, if I use ToastNotification in my app it works.

```
System.Exception was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024735
  Message=The specified path is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700A1)
  Source=Windows
  StackTrace:
       at Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotifier.AddToSchedule(ScheduledToastNotification scheduledToast)
```

I'm not opening any files or dealing with paths at this point and the exception definitely occurs on the line to launch a ScheduledToastNotification, I'm using Windows 10 Universal Application Platform but can't find any reference to this error or issue anywhere

Comment: I think the issue might be due to lack of support for this on Desktop as it works fine in the Windows 10 Mobile emulator - in Windows 8.1 this was the case but assumed this should work on both Mobile and Desktop, not sure if this is an API bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error "The specified path is invalid" was due to the API in the build of Windows 10 not yet supporting the API call, documentation for Windows 8.1 mentions that ScheduledToastNotification was not supported, however in the 10240 build of Windows 10 this API call now is fully supported on desktop and mobile